# Weak solution is strong solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, variational-analysis

I came across the following statement:  If $V=\{v \in C^1[0,1])~ |~ v(0)=0\}, ~~f \in C([0,1])$ and $u \in C^2([0,1])$ then any solution to

\begin{equation}
u(0)=0 ~~\text{and}~~ \text{for all}~~ v \in V  \int_0^1u'(t)v'(t)dt=\int_0^1 f(t)v(t)dt
\end{equation}
is a solution to
\begin{equation}
-u''(t)=f(t)~~ \text{for all}~ t \in [0,1]  ~~~~~~\text{with}~~~~~~~~ u(0)=0 ~~~~~~~~~~\text{and} ~~~~~~~~ u'(1)=0
\end{equation}
and vice versa.

I can see why any strong solution is a weak solution since we can multiply the equation
\begin{equation}
-u''(t)=f(t)
\end{equation}
with a test function $v \in V$ and integrate over the intervall $[0,1]$. Using the boundary conditions we obtain
\begin{equation}
-\int_0^1u''(t)v(t)dt=-u'(t)v(t)|_{[0,1]}+\int_0^1u'(t)v'(t)=\int_0^1u'(t)v'(t)dt.
\end{equation}
Hence, any strong solution is a weak solution.
I'm aware that the condition $u\in C^2[0,1]$ is crucial for the other direction but I still fail to understand how to prove it properly. Could anyone show me why our weak solution is a strong solution (in this particular case)?

Comment: In your definition of a weak solution, you need more regularity in $V$, otherwise the integral is not defined. For example $v\in C^1$ or $v'\in L^1_{\text{loc}}$. Then note that the weak solution satisfies $-u''=f$ in the sense of the distributions, so it all amounts to proving that if the derivative of a distribution $T$ is continuous, then this distribution is a $C^1$ function.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - I meant $v \in C^1$. I'm a beginner in the subject of distributions, could you please elaborate your answer a little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ u$ be a weak solution such that $ {u} \in  {\mathcal{C}}^{1} \left(\left[0 , 1\right]\right)$. Let

\begin{equation} F \left(t\right) = \int_{t}^{1}f \left(s\right) d s\end{equation}

Let $ {\phi} \in  {\mathcal{C}}_{0}^{0}$ be an arbitrary continuous
function such that $ {\phi} \left(0\right) = {\phi} \left(1\right) = 0$ and let

\begin{equation}v \left(t\right) = \int_{0}^{t}{\phi} \left(s\right) d s \in  V\end{equation}

We have $ {v'} = {\phi}$. By the weak solution property we have

\begin{equation}\int_{0}^{1}\left({u'} \left(t\right)-F \left(t\right)\right) {\phi} \left(t\right) d t = \int_{0}^{1}{u'} \left(t\right) {v'} \left(t\right) d t-{\left[F \left(t\right) v \left(t\right)\right]}_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}f \left(t\right) v \left(t\right) = 0\end{equation}

because $ F \left(1\right) = 0$ and $v \left(0\right) = 0$. The value of this
integral is zero for every function $ {\phi} \in  {\mathcal{C}}_{0}^{0}$ and this proves that

\begin{equation}{u'} \left(t\right) = F \left(t\right)\end{equation}

Note in particular that $ {\lim }_{t \rightarrow  1} {u'} \left(t\right) = 0$.

It follows that $ {u'} \in  {\mathcal{C}}^{1}$ hence $ u \in  {\mathcal{C}}^{2}$ and $ u$ is a strong solution.